# How do I install Ubuntu on an Asus EeePc t91mt

Tags: 12.04, asus, eeepc, poulsbo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have tried Ubuntu 12.04.1 in an Asus EeePc t91mt; In live Cd mode it works fine (touch screen, wifi, bluetooth,..), but when I installed it and restarted the screen stay black and nothing happen(it could be the video card driver).

But i do not understand why in the liveCd mode it works and it does not work when I install it. Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please check the answers in this similar question: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem (just got a t91mt for my wife).  Here is the solution:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo#Post_installation

Basically the GMA500 driver does NOT like the splash screen when loading, so you must disable that.  Might be other fixes, but this ones easy and it's not like the splash screen is worth much.

You want to do Options 1 and 2,
and use:
1)Switch to a console - Ctrl-Alt-F1
2)Restart X with 'sudo service lightdm restart' 
to be able to get to the gui to fix the problem

Also- just a suggestion, Ubuntu still ran pretty slow at bit glitchy.  We have found that Lubuntu works much better for the t91mt